# Firebase Web Hosting

Tags: firebase, hosting

What is the correct way to configure the firebase.json file to handle when a link is right clicked and a new tab is opened. I am consistently redirected to the 404 page.

Comment: I am fairly certain this has nothing to do with the firebase.json file. In fact if you delete it, and get a fresh copy nothing will change. Perhaps check if the link is correct in the HTML.

Comment: The interesting thing is that if I run the program locally with localhost, the problem does not exist, it is only when it is hosted on firebase. This is why I have come to this conclusion.

Comment: You won't be able to deploy the site without that file. I see your point but somethings could change if you had to deal with CORS.

Comment: follow this tutorial step by step or watch youtube video on this blog. you will understand everything.   http://codingaffairs.blogspot.com/2017/06/how-to-firebase-web-hosting-and-connect.html